# Kafka and OpenJDK

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have installed Apache Kafka with Java 8 and Oracle JDK. However my company is thinking to move to OpenJDK

Is there any issues or considerations to implement and use Kafka with OpenJDK?

Is there some documentation about this relationship (apache kafka<->OpenJDK).

Comment: I've googled a few cases in which people use OpenJDK with no problems: https://www.tutorialkart.com/apache-kafka/install-apache-kafka-on-ubuntu/ https://linuxhint.com/install-apache-kafka-ubuntu/

Comment: Thanks a lot Fabio. Perhaps is there something on RHEL ?

Comment: CentOS seems to work as well: https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-apache-kafka-on-centos-7

Answer (score 1):

Oracle JDK is recommended, but Zulu or OpenJDK will work fine for most purposes. OS shouldn't be a factor because Java is cross platform.

In fact, the Ansible Playbooks provided by Confluent will install OpenJDK as a prerequisite for Zookeeper and Kafka.

You might even be able to use Java 9 or 10 with the latest release 2.0 of Kafka, though I'm not sure if the same can be said for Zookeeper

Answer (score 0):

As a datapoint, Confluent's (the biggest company behind Kafka) Docker images use Azul Zulu themselves ([source](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/7.3/installation/docker/installation.html#supported-platforms)).

> The Confluent Docker images are tested and shipped with Azul Zulu OpenJDK.

So I would take it as a strong proof that everything works fine. Not to mention that we test it extensively internally.

Just for you to know, you can also consider trying out [Azul Platform Prime](https://docs.azul.com/prime/prime-quick-start-tar), which OpenJDK-based optimized JVM which can give you quite an improvement of Kafka's performance in terms of throughput and latency. Details can be found [here](https://www.azul.com/blog/kafka-throughput-on-azul-platform-prime-vs-openjdk/).

*Disclaimer: I work for Azul, so I'm obviously biased.*